# copy the same row from multiple sheets into one sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I need to copy the same row from multiple sheets into one row.

Example: I have an excel file with 5 sheets. I have to copy the 10th row (or the 15th row, or the 21th row) of every sheet in a 6th sheet, in the order of the sheets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will copy **7th** row from all **first 5 sheets** into **6th** sheet.

```
Sub row_copy()

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1

Sheets(i).Rows(7).Copy Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1)

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for **6** sheets and rows # **7**:

```
Sub copyrow()
    Dim Nrow As Long, Nsheet As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Nrow = 7
    Nsheet = 6

    For i = 1 To Nsheet - 1
        Sheets(i).Cells(Nrow, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(Nsheet).Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The row # 7 from the first 5 sheets will be copied into the 6<sup>th</sup> sheet.

Comment: is there a way to modify this code to copy only the values not the formulas in row #7?