# Copy values from same row on multiple worksheets to one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code from this similar question:
[copy the same row from multiple sheets into one sheet in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835442/copy-the-same-row-from-multiple-sheets-into-one-sheet-in-excel?newreg=975c05dce9b5425e8d764)

The second answer (from Gary's Student) features the code, and it works perfectly for most of my data. The code in question will take the same row from each worksheet in an excel file, and put all of those rows into the last worksheet.

Problem is, some of my data is made of references. When I run the code, I don't want to copy over "= B12", but I want the paste special value. Can anyone edit the code to work like this?

Comment: You should be able to use the `PasteSpecial` method to paste the cell values instead of formulas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel. Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding the `.value` to the rows you are interested in should solve your reference issue.

```
Sub row_copy()

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1

   Sheets(6).Rows(i) = Sheets(i).Rows(7).Value 'added .value and reversed order of that code

Next i

End Sub
```

### Edit

The second answer

```
Sub copyrow()
Dim Nrow As Long, Nsheet As Long
Dim i As Long

Nrow = 7
Nsheet = 6

For i = 1 To Nsheet - 1
    Sheets(Nsheet).Rows(i) = Sheets(i).Rows(7).Value
    'Sheets(i).Cells(Nrow, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(Nsheet).Cells(i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

A way to be sure and get every sheet except the sheet you are writing to.

```
Sub row_copy()
Dim i As Long
i = 1

With Application.Sheets("Your Sheet Name")

    For Each Item In Worksheets

        If Item.Name <> .Name Then
            .Rows(i) = Sheets(i).Rows(7).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is any special cell formatting you are trying to preserve.  This will not do that for you.

Comment: I am using the second code, from Gary's Student's answer, as the first code didn't work for me. I thought by simply putting .Value at the end it would work, but the code didn't run. I am not trying to preserve any formatting.

Comment: @Kaynex this code didn't run?  hmm Do you have a sheet with index 6?